# Store MySQL database in EBS volume

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I took help from this article [link](http://spruce.it/noise/setting-up-a-proper-lamp-stack-on-aws-ec2-ebs/) to move my database to be stored in EBS volume, I mounted the volume and did all those steps. I rebooted my instance and when i tried again it says connection refused.
I had to follow these steps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23922469/1129179) to edit my fstab file(not the files mentioned in the link, they were all fine). I had to deleted all the mount sql lines:

```
mount /etc/mysql
mount /var/lib/mysql
mount /var/lib/mysql
```

and after again reattaching the EBS to my original instance i could login to it. So my question is did i do something wrong or what do i need to do to make my mysql Database be stored in the EBS and not on the instance. I don't wanna take a risk again editing fstab.

Comment: You can always run `mount -a` to check if fstab is correct.